# System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file ' FilePath' because it is being used by another process.File.Copy

Tags: vb.net

I am using File.Copy function to copy the File from one Location to another in For Loop as we have to copy that file in 200 different location. But i am getting error in mid of the process. Below is the Code i used.

```
 If File.Exists(FromfileLocation) Then
   File.Copy(FromfileLocation, TofileLocation, True)
 End If
```

Comment: looks like the file is opened by another program?

Comment: If you are copying the same file to 200 different destinations,why test if File.Exists each time? Maybe test once then perform copy in loop. Possibly one fewer IO operation inside that loop will help,  Also check which destination file it's failing on.  If the same one each time, could be a write permission issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in another way without have the problem “used by another proccess”

Try this:

```
   Public Shared Sub CopyMyFile(FromfileLocation As String, TofileLocation As String)

    Try

        If File.Exists(FromfileLocation) Then
            Using fs As FileStream = File.OpenRead(FromfileLocation)
                Using sw As FileStream = File.Open(TofileLocation, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
                    Dim b(1024 * 4) As Byte
                    Do
                        Dim readed As Integer = fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length)
                        If readed > 0 Then
                            sw.Write(b, 0, readed)
                        Else
                            Exit Do
                        End If
                    Loop
                End Using
            End Using
        End If

    Catch ioEx As FileNotFoundException
        Console.WriteLine(ioEx.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```